# SQL hierarchical query: find full tree given an id of any parent-child (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm struggling a hierarchical SQL query (using Oracle). Say I have table of widgets with unique ids. A widget can be copied only once, and we track the parent id from the new widget. For example, lets say widget 100 gets copied and becomes widget 101, then 103, then 105.

```
id    parent_id
100   
101   100
102
103   101
104
105   103

CREATE TABLE WIDGETS (ID NUMBER NOT NULL, PARENT_ID NUMBER);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (100, null);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (101, 100);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (102, null);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (103, 101);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (104, null);
INSERT INTO WIDGETS (ID, PARENT_ID) VALUES (105, 103);
```

(102 and 104 is just dummy data)

I'm trying to make a query that displays the full history of a widget, using any of the ids in the relationship.

So if I give the query an id of '103' (or '100'... or '105'), I'd expect the query to return something like this:

```
id    parent_id    
100   
101   100
103   101
105   103
```

I've tried using CONNECT BY PRIOR, but I would need the start by ID to use start with. For example, I can display the full tree giving the query the origin id:

```
select parent_id as from_id, id as to_id
from WIDGETS
start with id = 100
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;

from_id   to_id
null      100
100       101
101       103
103       105
```

But what if I don't necessarily know the start with id? Is it possible to find the origin ID and then get the full tree from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the start by traversing the tree backwards until you hit a leaf.

`SELECT parent_id AS from_id, ID AS to_id
FROM WIDGETS
START WITH ID = 
  ( SELECT ID
    FROM WIDGETS
    WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1
    START WITH ID = 105
    CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR parent_id
  )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id;`

Comment: If you changed `START WITH ID = ` to `START WITH ID IN ` it would even cope with adding the pair (101, 104).

Answer (score 0):

@Input below is the input id you pass to Stored Procedure. Try this, hope it helps:

```
DECLARE @Parent int;

WHILE (Select @Parent = PARENT_ID From Widgets Where ID = @Input) Is NOT NULL
BEGIN
Set @Input = @Parent
END
Set @Parent = @Input

declare @Hierarchy table(Member int)
INSERT INTO @Hierarchy(Member) Values (@Parent)
WHILE (Select @Input = ID From Widgets Where PARENT_ID = @Parent) Is NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @Parent = @Input
INSERT INTO @Hierarchy(Member) Values (@Parent)
END

Select * From @Hierarchy
```

Comment: Why use stored procedures for a trivial hierarchical query? Definite de-merit!

Comment: I thought he is trying to create a stored proc.

Comment: Why did you think that? There is absolutely nothing in the original post to suggest the OP was looking for a stored procedure solution.

Comment: I don't know why I thought that and I feel no desire to explain my thought process.